# plupload removeFiles

Tags: javascript, upload, plupload

I'm trying to remove files with not allowed extensions on the FilesAdded event.  (I can't use the filter parameter as I need an exclusive list).

I have some code a bit like this:

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    var count = files.length;
    var i = 0;
    for (i;i<count;i++) {
        var validExt = validate(files[i].name);
        if(!validExt){
```

I need to remove the files added if the extensions aren't valid.  I've tried the following:

```
uploader.splice(i,1)
uploader.removeFile(files[i]);
uploader.refresh();
```

The FilesRemoved event is fired, but removed files still get uploaded with uploader.start().

I don't know if this is a bug in the program, or too obscure to expect an easy answer to, but if anyone can help, I'd be really grateful.  I don't *think* I'm missing anything obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things...

1st you have to bind the filesAdded event after calling the init() function.

```
uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {...}
```

2nd you can filter the files extension using the prop filters when defining plupload

```
uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        ...,
        filters: [
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpeg,jpg,gif,png" }
        ],
        ...
    });
```

3rd here's a working sample to remove files from plupload

```
$.each(uploader.files, function (i, file) {
    if (file && file.id != currentFile.id) {
        uploader.removeFile(file);
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: *Hi. Thanks.  I think I probably found a fix way back.  To clear up, I think you do pass the file object rather than the ID.  Works for me at least in the current plupload release.  I'm not sure yours is the best answer - I don't think I was using jQuery, but it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

When there is no upload progress and you want to remove all queued files from uploader list:

> var queueLength = uploader.files.length;
>
> for (i = 0; i < queueLength; i++) {
>
> > if (uploader.files[0] && uploader.files[0] !== undefined) {
> >
> > > uploader.removeFile(uploader.files[0]);
> >
> > }
>
> }

Note: If you try to remove files by index, some files are left in the list; because every time a file item is removed from the list, it is refreshed and indexes are resorted.

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me, unfortunately I spent a lot of time with this and came to the same conclusion before I saw this answer..

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the id of the file you want to remove to removeFile:

> `uploader.removeFile(files[i].id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback "QueueChanged", it works for me as well.

```
uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function(up){

  var file_count = up.files.length;
  for(i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
    if(i != (file_count - 1)) up.removeFile(up.files[i]);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    if( files.length > 1 )
    {
        $.each(files, function(i, file) {
            up.removeFile(file);    
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: consider adding some comments to your solution and formatting the code, it will make it more understable for the OP and future visitors